# Matlab - MultiStart gets stuck using fmincon

Tags: matlab, optimization, estimation

I am currently trying to run a minimum-distance estimation of a dynamic search model with the MultiStart routine and fmincon and a bounded parameter space. My problem right now is that the routine gets stuck at a random point of the estimation, i.e. at some point one of the iterations gets stuck in an infinite loop or so and nothing moves forward.

My problem structure is the following:

```
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon',...
    'objective',@(x)objective(x,fixedInput),...
    'x0',x_0,...
    'lb',[0 0 0 0 0.001 0], 'ub',[50 1500 30 79 1 1],...
    optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point','Display','off','UseParallel',true,));

ms = MultiStart('UseParallel',true,'Display','iter','StartPointsToRun','bounds');
```

The objective function has as output the weighted distance between supplied empirical moments and parametric counterparts of the dynamic model that I aim to fit to the data.

I run into the same problem no matter which algorithm I choose for the fmincon problems (though the process gets stuck much later when I use active-set instead of interior-point or sqp). I know that MultiStart has the MaxTime option, but this is not convenient in my case as I want to run the estimation on a large set of starting values (~2000) and the whole estimation stops too early then.

Does anyone know about a way to circumvent this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best,
banan

EDIT:

I get the following output when interrupting the routine:

```
Operation terminated by user during search(line 110)


In objective(line 42)
    s_par = search(x, fixed);

In parallel_function>@(x)objective(x,fixedInput)

In finDiffEvalAndChkErr

In parfinitedifferences

In parallel_function (line 478)
        consume(base, limit, F(base, limit, supply(base, limit)));

In parfinitedifferences

In nlconst (line 347)
                parfinitedifferences(XOUT,lb,ub,f, ...

In fmincon (line 750)
    nlconst(funfcn,X,l,u,full(A),B,full(Aeq),Beq,confcn,options,defaultopt, ...

In fmultistart

In fmultistart

In parallel_function>make_general_channel/channel_general (line 914)
                O = F(C{:});

In remoteParallelFunction (line 38)
    out = parallel.internal.pool.serialize(feval(channel, channelArgs{:}));

Operation terminated by user during distcomp.remoteparfor/getCompleteIntervals (line 127)


In parallel_function>distributed_execution (line 820)
    [tags, out] = P.getCompleteIntervals(chunkSize);

In parallel_function (line 587)
    R = distributed_execution(...

In fmultistart

In MultiStart/run (line 268)
           fmultistart(problem,startPointSets,msoptions);

In MinDist_HM (line 42)
[theta_est,fval,exitflag,outp,manymins] = run(ms,problem,2000)
```

Comment: It is unlikely this can be answered without more information. Are you sure it's an infinite loop? (It probably isn't; just some slow iteration.) What is getting stuck? Is a single call to `objective` getting stuck or is `fmincon` going through a vast number of iterations? If you can create a minimal, self-contained example, that would really help. But we would understand that is hard to do with a problem like this.

Comment: I must agree that is is pretty hard to produce a self contained example here as the underlying search function is quite complex. I added the Matlab output after the termination, which might give some clues that I don't see? How can I find out if it is a single call or fmincon going through numbers of iterations? Thank you drhagen!

Comment: You could turn the display for `fmincon` to `iter` so that something is printed at each iteration. If it stops, then you know it is stuck in `objective`. If it prints endlessly, then you know it is actually stuck iterating.

Comment: OK, it seems to be stuck in the objective function as it does not move forward from a certain iteration in fmincon. Is there a way to induce a time limit for each iteration here?

Comment: No, that is not possible. If the problem is in your objective function, then only you can fix your objective function. Try to figure out what kind of inputs is causing it to fail add constraints to keep it from going there.

Comment: Following your hint I dug deeper in the objective and actually found the issue. There was a one model specific configuration parameter that exploded once one of the estimated parameters reached a certain value, causing virtually infinite computation times. Thanks for the guidance drhagen, it all runs smooth now after accounting for this pattern. Much appreciated!